# How can I set the colour of a listbox item to match the colour of a picture box I have clicked

Tags: c#, listbox

I have a listbox with 100 items and several picture boxes each of different colours.  When I click a picture box I want the background of the currently selected item in the listbox to change to the colour of the picturebox.  I think I need some way of calling the listbox drawitem event from within the click event of the picturebox but I am not sure how to do this.

So far I have the following code but this just sets the selected item to the default colour of blue:

```
    private void redBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Color redBoxColour = redBox.BackColor;


    }

    private void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Index<0) return;
        //if the item state is selected them change the back color 
        if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected)
            e = new DrawItemEventArgs(e.Graphics, 
                                      e.Font, 
                                      e.Bounds, 
                                      e.Index,
                                      e.State ^ DrawItemState.Selected,
                                      e.ForeColor, 
                                      e.BackColor);

        // Draw the background of the ListBox control for each item.
        e.DrawBackground();
        // Draw the current item text
        e.Graphics.DrawString(listBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString(),e.Font, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault);
        // If the ListBox has focus, draw a focus rectangle around the selected item.
        e.DrawFocusRectangle();


    }
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: What do you want to be the back color? Try to replace e.BackColor with any desired value where you are doing ... e.State ^ DrawItemState.Selected, e.ForeColor,  **e.BackColor**);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a variable to store the color of selected PictureBox:

```
Color selectedColor;
```

Then you can set this variable value (color) when you click on a PictureBox through a Click event. All picture boxes should call this event when clicked:

```
    private void picBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PictureBox selectedPic = (PictureBox)sender;
        selectedColor = selectedPic.BackColor;
        listBox1.Refresh(); // to update the actual selected item
    }
```

And modify your DrawItem function to use this color, instead of e.BackColor that you are using currently:

```
private void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Index<0) return;
    //if the item state is selected them change the back color 
    if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected)
        e = new DrawItemEventArgs(e.Graphics, 
                                  e.Font, 
                                  e.Bounds, 
                                  e.Index,
                                  e.State ^ DrawItemState.Selected,
                                  e.ForeColor, 
                                  selectedColor);

    // Draw the background of the ListBox control for each item.
    e.DrawBackground();
    // Draw the current item text
    e.Graphics.DrawString(listBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString(),e.Font, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault);
    // If the ListBox has focus, draw a focus rectangle around the selected item.
    e.DrawFocusRectangle();
}
```

You need to take some steps before that I don't know if you did:

1) Add this to the form constructor:

```
listBox1.DrawItem += new System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventHandler(listBox1_DrawItem);
```

2) Change the listBox property DrawMode to OwnerDrawFixed

Comment: This has really helped thanks :)  However when I select a new item in the listbox it sets that to the right colour but the last selected item is redrawn back to the original backcolour (i.e. transparent).  How can I make sure the colour on the last box selected persists?

Comment: Are you still having problems? Some days have passed and I forgot this comment =/
Anyway... As Hadron said below, it's much easier if you can use ListView. And if you use WPF instead of Windows Form, it becomes far better. In case you're still working in the previous solution, tell me and I try to help you :D

Answer (score 0):

Use `ListView` instead. Everything you can do with `ListBox` you can also with `ListView`.

Then simply change the selected indices BackColor like so:

```
    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < listView1.SelectedIndices.Count; i++)
            listView1.Items[listView1.SelectedIndices[i]].BackColor = pictureBox1.BackColor;
    }
```

Your going to save yourself a lot of trouble